# How to write STR_TO_DATE() mysql function in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I have written a query in CakePHP like this:-

```
$customerMovings = $this->Customer->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers 
                            AS Customer WHERE Customer.buyer_id = '".$id."' 
                            AND Customer.isCancel = '0' AND Customer.isDeposit = '1' AND Customer.move_date >= '".$moveDate."' 
                            AND Customer.move_date <= '".$move72Date."' 
                            Order by move_date ASC,STR_TO_DATE(move_time,'%l:%i %p')");
```

How can I write the same using CakePHP ORM query? Something like this:-

```
$customerMovings = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "Customer.isCancel" =>0,
        "Customer.isDeposit" =>1,
        "Customer.move_date >= " =>$moveDate,
        "Customer.move_date <= " =>$move72Date,
        "OR" => array(
            'Customer.id' =>$selectedCustomer,
            "Customer.creater_id" =>$id
        )
     ),
    'order'=>array(
        "Customer.move_date"=>"ASC",
        "STR_TO_DATE(Customer.move_time,'%l:%i %p')"=>'ASC'
    )
));
```

Comment: Did you try our initial thoughts? If so, what were its results?

Comment: Please always mention the CakePHP version that you are using (ideally the _exact_ version found on the last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`), and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Cake3 solution**

you can create any mysql function ising the `func()` method of the Query object.

Is is explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions) in the cookbook

> In addition to the above functions, the `func()` method can be used to
>   create any generic SQL function such as `year`, `date_format`, `convert`,
>   etc.

The arguments are passed as an array and you have to tell which are bounds parameters and which are identifiers

So in your case

```
->order(function ($exp,  $q) {
    return $q->func()->str_to_date([
        'Customer.move_time' => 'identifiers', // this tells cake that
                                               // Customer.move_time
                                               // is the name of a column and
                                               // not a strimg
        '%l:%i %p'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Given the singular identifiers, the old array style, and the find options usage, it looks like the OP is using CakePHP 2.

Comment: @ndm I though the same but he was also talking about the ORM and is a term not often used in cake2. Anyway I'll edit my answer